# Prove that $ \int_0^1 f(x)dx - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac{k}{n}) = O(\frac{1}{n}) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let the function $ f(x) $ is bounded and monotone on $[0,1]$. Prove that

$ \int_0^1 f(x)dx - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac{k}{n}) = O(\frac{1}{n}) $

It is clear that $ \int_0^1 f(x)dx - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac{k}{n}) \to 0 $ if $ n \to \infty $

But I have no idea how to prove that it is exactly $ O(\frac 1n) $.

Thanks for the help! Do not judge strictly I am just starting to study integral calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, as f is increasing,

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) dx=  \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}} f(x) dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}} f(\frac{k}{n}) dx \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n  f(\frac{k}{n}) $$
and
$$ \int_0^1 f(x) dx=  \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}} f(x) dx \geq 
\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}} f(\frac{k-1}{n}) dx $$
$$\geq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n  f(\frac{k-1}{n}) \geq \frac{f(0)}{n}-\frac{f(1)}{n} + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n  f(\frac{k}{n}) $$

Hence

$$\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{n} \leq \int_0^1 f(x) dx - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n  f(\frac{k}{n}) \leq 0$$

Comment: did you forget an integral in the second line?

Comment: I skipped a step, will add to lessen possible confusion

Comment: Good solution, but I think only the first inequality is required because you get $\int f \leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})}{n} + \frac{f(0)}{n}$ and the second term is $O(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: ...therefore you've proven a stronger one - $\Theta(\frac{1}{n})$. Well done!